nethunter drivers issues
hiHello,
I'm trying to install Linux on my Galaxy A71 device and I'm having problems.
I'm trying to install drivers and fix the problem with the MAKE command.
I tried reading online and solving it myself and everything led me to the uname-r command
And I saw that something strange appears to me, which may be why I can't install the drivers or the headers.
The output in the uname -r command is: 4.14.190.27200287-abA716fxxsbdxb1
I'm starting to go crazy with this and I need your help!
Thanks in advance

Your title hints at some driver issues and your question mentions issues with the make command, but you never say anything about what these issues are.  Please update your question with the relevant commands that you are trying to use, and the unaltered output that clearly shows the error messages etc. that you are seeing.

Okay, I'll try to be more detailed.
I try to connect an ALFA wifi edepter and the device appears to me when I do LSUSB but does not appear to me when I do IWCONFIG.
When I try to install the drivers (rtl8812au) with the MAKE command I get this error:
https://ibb.co/WPsHj6L

And I know that the solution to this is to install headers, but again it goes back to the kernel and there are no headers associated with this kernel

@Kusalananda plz if u can help me?
